# Select2 does not allow you to enter text into the input if set to multiple => false But all OK if multiple => true

Tags: jquery-select2

I need to set to page Select2. If I set 'multiple' => false in the configuration, then in the displayed Select2 cannot enter text and search. If you put 'multiple' => true, then everything works fine.

```
$html .= Select2::widget([
            'name' => 'select_patterns_' . $model->id,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'Шаблон',
                'multiple' => false
            ],
            'hideSearch' => true,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'minimumInputLength' => 3,
                'ajax'=>[
                    'url'=> Url::to(['persons/get-user']),
                    'dataType' => 'json',
                    'delay' => 250,
                    'cache' => true,
                ],
                'allowClear' => true,
            ],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'change' => 'function() {
                        var selectedIds = $(this).val();
                        console.log(selectedIds);
                    }'
                ]
            ]);
```

Comment: Where does what you have shown have _anything_ to do with PHP? This should not mention "(PHP)" in the title, and not be tagged `php` either, if you don't really have a problem _with_ PHP. (Question edited.)